# How to move static variables from a class to another class when refactoring in IntelliJ or Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, refactoring

Suppose `Class A` with some static parameters:

```
public Class A {
    public static final String KEY_1="key1"
    public static final String KEY_2="key2"
    ...
}
```

The static parameters are used repeatedly in the project. When refactoring, I want to move them to another class, say `Class B`; but doing so I have to update every use case of them, e.g. `A.KEY_1` to `B.KEY_2`, manually.

Is there any way to do so automatically in Android Studio or IntelliJ?
What I have already tried is selecting the lines containing the parameters and pressing F6 which opens a refactoring dialog, but going through it does not get me to what I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IntelliJ is **really** good at refactoring. Place your caret on the constant you want to move and do the following:

1. Refactor -> Move (with the default key bindings, this can also be done by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>).
2. You'll get a dialog asking you for the fully qualified name of the class you want to move it to (don't worry - just start typing and IntelliJ will autocomplete for you) and a menu to choose the visibility modified you want to assign to the variable/constant.
3. Click the "Refactor" button
4. Enjoy

Comment: Thank you! The trick was to place the caret on the parameter I want to refactor rather than selecting its whole line.